# The catheti of a right triangle with given hypotenuse and radius of inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> Triangle $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with $\measuredangle ACB=90^\circ$. Let $AB=c$ and the radius of the inscribed circle be $r$. Find the catheti and the area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$.

We now that the radius $r=\frac12(a+b-c)$. Furthermore, $c^2=a^2+b^2$. How to find the lengths from here?

Comment: LYI, you didn't have to [repost this here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668280/1508)! You can edit your posts just by clicking on `edit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a=c_1+r$, $b=c_2+r$ and: 
$$
\cases{
(c_1+r)^2+(c_2+r)^2=(c_1+c_2)^2\\
c_1+c_2=c\\
}
$$
Solving you can find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! What are $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova It should be evident from the definitions above and from a sketch.

Comment: I do have a sketch. But I really do not find it "evident". What is evident for you, does not make it evident for me. Are these the projections of the catheti on $AB$?

Comment: The leg of the triangle can be split up into the length of the inradius, and another length which is $c_1$. The other leg can be split into $r$ and $c_2$. Because external tangents  to a circle are the same length, then $c$ can be comprised of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. If $M,N$ and $P$ are the tangent points with $AB,BC$ and $AC$ respectively, then $AP=AM=c_1,BM=BN=c_2$ and $CP=CN=r$.

Comment: I have some difficulties with the system.

Comment: For the first equation: $$(c_1+r)^2+(c_2+r)^2=(c_1+c_2)^2 \Leftrightarrow r^2+c_1r+c_2r=c_1c_2.$$

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Just find $c_2$ from the second equation, plug the result into the first equation (after expanding and simplifying) and solve for $c_1$.

Comment: You'll get two results, corresponding to $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Okay. After expanding and simplifying the first equation I got $r^2+c_1r+c_2r=c_1c_2.$ From the second equation $c_2=c-c_1$. Plugging the result into the first equation gives $r^2+c_1r+(c-c_1)r=c_1(c-c_1)$ which I cannot solve for $c_1$.

Comment: It's a quadratic equation. Do you know how to solve them?

Comment: $r^2+c_1r+(c-c_1)r=c_1(c-c_1) \Leftrightarrow r^2+c_1^2+cr-cc_1=0$. How is it quadratic?

Comment: The unknown is $c_1$, the other letters are just parameters (known quantities).

Comment: I haven't solved this type of quadratic equations, but I will try. So we can write it as $c_1^2-cc_1+cr+r^2=0$. The discriminant is $D=b^2-4ac=c^2-4(cr+r^2)=c^2-4cr-4r^2$. How to find the root of $D$? It would be nice if it was $+4r^2$.

Comment: You must leave that under square root. There is no "nice" simplification, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay. We will get two roots: $c_{1_1}=\dfrac{c-\sqrt{c^2-4cr-4r^2}}{2}$ and $c_{2_2}=\dfrac{c+\sqrt{c^2-4cr-4r^2}}{2}$. Are they both positive and should I continue the calculations with both of them?

Comment: Actually why do I get two results for $c_1$?

Comment: Compute $c_2=c-c_1$ and you'll understand why.

Comment: @Aretino, I did. We have $c_2=\dfrac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$. I am still not sure I understand why we get two results for $c_1$ from the quadratic.

Comment: @Aretino, can you help me here?

Comment: There is nothing to help: as you can see, the second value of $c_1$ is the same as the first value of $c_2$, and the first value of $c_1$ is the same as the second value of $c_2$. Hence the two solutions only amount at interchanging $c_1$ and $c_2$. But the triangle doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other solution plus a figure:[image]

We have:

$AB^2=BC^2+AC^2$

$BF=BD=c_1$

$AE=AD=c_2$

$AB=c$

$AC=c_2+r$ and $CB=c_1+r$ ⇒ $c_1^2+c_2^2+2r(c_1+c_2)+2r^2=c^2$

$c_1+c_2=c$ ⇒ $c_1^2+c_2^2+2 c_1c_2=c^2$

Subtracting two relations we get:

$$2rc+2r^2-2c_1c_2=0$$

⇒ $c_1c_2=rc+r^2$

$c_1+c_2=c$

Now we construct following quadratic equation to find $c_1$ and $c_2$:

$x^2-(c_1+c_2) x+ c_1c_2=0$

$x^2- c x +r^2+rc=0$

Which gives:

$x=\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4rc}}{2}=c_1$

$x=\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4rc}}{2}=c_2$

Example:

$c=105$ and $r=20$ gives:

$c_1=68.5$ and $c_2=36.5$ which results:

$CB=20+68.5=88.5$

$CA=20+36.5=56.5$