# The legs of a right triangle with given hypotenuse and radius of inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, quadrilateral

> Triangle $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with $\measuredangle ACB=90^\circ$. Let $AB=c$ and the radius of the inscribed circle be $r$. Find the catheti and the area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$.

[image]
Let $P,N$ and $M$ be the tangent points with $AB,BC$ and $CA$, respectively. The quadrilateral $MINC$ is a square. Therefore, $MI=IN=NC=CM=r.$ We have $AM=AP=c_1$ and $BN=BP=c_2$ as tangent segments. Now we have: $$\begin{cases} (c_1+r)^2+(c_2+r)^2=(c_1+c_2)^2 \\ c_1+c_2=c \Rightarrow c_2=c-c_1 \end{cases}.$$ After simplifying the first equation I got $r^2+c_1r+c_2r=c_1c_2$ and now let us plug $c_2=c-c_1$. We get the quadratic equation $c_1^2-cc_1+r^2+cr=0$ which has roots $c_1=\dfrac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$. I am not sure I understand what to do next and why we got two expressions for the same segment. What does that mean? If use use both the results in $c_2=c-c_1=\dfrac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$. What does mean?

Comment: Small, but key, sign error (or typo): If $c_1 = \tfrac12(c \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{\cdots})$, then $c_2 = \tfrac12(c \color{red}{\mp} \sqrt{\cdots})$. That is, if $c_1$ uses "$+$", then $c_2$ uses "$-$", and vice versa. So, the "two expressions for the same segment" are actually "the expressions for the two segments"! What's happening here is that the algebra can't tell the difference between $c_1$ and $c_2$. (If all you saw were your two equations could you?) So, the answer *must* be ambiguous about which length is which, and it's giving you both of them.

Comment: @Blue, Thank you for the response! I am trying to understand now. You are right. If $c_1$ uses "-", then $c_2$ uses "+", and vice versa. I don't understand what do you mean that the expressions are actually for the two segments. Which expressions are for the two segments?

Comment: Another (informal) way to write what you have is $$\{c_1,c_2\} = \tfrac12(c\pm\sqrt{\cdots})$$ The two values provided by the "$\pm$" are the two lengths you seek. You get to pick which is which.

Comment: @Blue, let me try to explain it again. Maybe this will help me to understand it better and also to ask you if I don't get something. When $c_1=\dfrac{c-\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$, $c_2=\dfrac{c+\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$. When $c_1=\dfrac{c+\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$, then $c_2=\dfrac{c-\sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$. Right? Doesn't this depend on the angles of $\triangle ABC$?

Comment: That is correct. From there, you can calculate the catheti and the area. But note: You don't have to do the work twice. If your first $c_1$ and $c_2$ yield catheti "this" and "that", then your second $c_1$ and $c_2$ will give you "that" and "this". And the area will be "$\tfrac12\cdot\text{this}\cdot\text{that}$" versus "$\tfrac12\cdot\text{that}\cdot\text{this}$". They're the *same* answers, because it doesn't (and *shouldn't*) matter which $c_i$ got the "$+$" and which got the "$-$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two solutions, because the triangle has two catheti. It is not unusual that the equation (if correctly composed) appears to be smarter than it was supposed by its construction.

In the considered case the equation gives the solutions for both catheti, and this is in fact inavoidable. Indeed you system of equations is symmetric with respect to $c_1$ and $c_2$. Therefore it must have in general case at least two solutions: $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$. Hence, it is not at all surprising that the equation for $c_i$ appears to be quadratic. And since the equation is quadratic, the solution of the problem is unique up to a congruence relation between the resulting triangles. Which one of the two solutions you name $c_1$ and which $c_2$ plays no role.

Your next step is to compute the catheti using the relations $a=c_1+r$ and $b=c_2+r $. The rest is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't understand what do you mean. We are solving the quadric eqution for $c_1$; not for the catheti of the triangle.

Comment: Now recall the definition of $c_{1,2}$ and add $r$ to obtain the values of catheti.

Comment: I really have not seen this before. I am solving a quadratic equation which has two roots $\dfrac{c\pm \sqrt{c^2-4r^2-4cr}}{2}$.

Comment: One root for one cathet, and the other for the second.  It is perfect, is not it?